# Adding <aside> to the WYSIWYG

Tags: html, wysiwyg, html5

I'm trying to add the `<aside>` tag to the WYSIWYG, just like you can add a blockquote. (Basically have a button to wrap the element in an `<aside>` tag)

I can't seem to find out how to add it by programming means, and things like the plugin Advanced TinyMCE doesn't seem to contain the option.

So how can I add a custom tag to the WYSIWYG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE has a 'formats' dropdown that you can add options to:

> This option enables you to add more advanced style formats for text
>   and other elements to the editor. The value of this option will be
>   rendered as styles in the styleselect dropdown toolbar item.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats

The first thing you need to do is add this dropdown to the editor. WordPress does not enable it by default:

```
function wpse_307115_mce_buttons( $buttons ) {
    if ( ! in_array( 'styleselect', $buttons ) ) {
        array_splice( $buttons, 1, 0, 'styleselect' );
    }

    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'wpse_307115_mce_buttons' );
```

Then you can use the `tiny_mce_before_init` hook to add [the necessary configuration options](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats) to the editor:

```
function wpse_307115_tiny_mce_init( $init_array ) {
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Aside',
            'block' => 'aside',
        ),
    ) );

    return $init_array;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse_307115_tiny_mce_init' );
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly.